# Ejecutar función de otro controlador enviando parametros

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mvc, revisión-de-código

Tengo a **Controller1** el cual contiene una función llamada actualizarCartera($parametro1, $parametro2, $parametro3), desde **Controller2** ¿Cómo hago para ejecutar esta función?, ¿Cómo debo incluír a **Controller1** en **Controller2**?

Answer (score 2):

No me parece viable llamar a una funcion de un controlador, desde otro controlador...

Lo que yo haria crearia un `trait` donde ahi defino la funcion que ocupare en 1 o más controladores y luego la llamaria...

```
trait TestTrait {

    public function funcionTest() {
       //Codigo
    }
}
```

Me imagino que la idea de llamar desde X controladores a 1 función es reutilizar el codigo, dentro de las definiciones de `trait` :

> Los trait son un mecanismo para la reutilización de código en lenguajes de herencia

Y en la definicion de tus controladores

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\TestTrait;

class Controller1 extends Controller {
    use TestTrait;
}

class Controller2 extends Controller {
    use TestTrait ;
}
```

Comment: Aquí en mi ingoracia ... en que lugar debo definir trait ?

Comment: @SantiagoMuñoz esto todo depende de la arquitectura que tengas en tu proyecto, por ejemplo te pregunto ¿Donde estan tus controladores? Cual es la ruta especifica `App\Http\Controllers` ?

Comment: Si, mi ruta es `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: Quiere decir que tus controladores estan todos en un namespace que se llama Controller, tu puedes definir tus Trait en `App`  y cuando lo llames debes especificar su ruta `App\TestTrait `

Comment: Vale, probaré y te cuento

Comment: @SantiagoMuñoz edite mi respuesta, por si te aclara mas el asunto!

Answer (score 1):

El fin de un controlador (normalmente) no es comunicarse con otro controlador, si necesitan hablar entre ellos deben hacerlo por medio de un modelo, servicio, repositorio u otra capa, dependiendo el diseño de la aplicación y lo que se desee hacer.

La respuesta de @sioesi es perfectamente válida y correcta, aunque no estoy totalmente de acuerdo. Me gusta más usar los traits para complementar interfaces y así mantener el código ordenado y aplicado, de lo contrario creo que se vuelve un poco aleatorio poner traits aquí y allá y considero que se pierde un poco el control del código, además que se puede caer fácilmente en malas prácticas:

```
interface SerVivo
{
    public alimentarse();
    public descansar();
}

trait Mamiferos
{
    public alimentarse() {
        echo 'con la boca';
    }

    public descansar() {
        echo 'dormir acostado';
    }
}

class Humanos implements SerVivo
{
    use Mamiferos;

    public mostrarFelicidad() {
        echo 'reir';
    }
}

class Perros implements SerVivo
{
    use Mamiferos;

    public mostrarFelicidad() {
        echo 'mover la cola';
    } 
}
```

Comment: no paso nada por aqui jejeje :;D